# What is the character limit for event description of a Google Calendar?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

What is the maximum number of characters allowed in an Event Description (including spaces, punctuation, and URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currrntly no documented limit for the length of the description in an [event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#:%7E:text=description) in google calendar.

I suspect that this would be due to the fact that google could change it.

[image]

I suggest you just try and save as much as you can in there and then handle any errors as they may come.   TBH if memory services they just chop off what doesn't fit and dont respond with an error.

Comment: I tried and found it that it has  limit of 8191 char for plain text

Comment: Ruchi, I believe you, but your comment was a year ago and I just tried and I got a max of 808 plain text character (without linebreaks or spaces at all).  Yikes, I have some very old appointments which have important data in there and I know it wasn't that short in previous years.  I'll have to check if it does go away.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like that the size of the event, including all data must not be more than 10KB.